# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

I wrote a code in asp.net that read data from files and draw a graph.

It worked but after awhile when i run the program, this exception arise

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll"

in this statement in the code:

```
if (File.Exists(fName)) <----(here is the exception)
{
    stream = File.Open(fName, FileMode.Open);
    g_day = Deserialize(stream);
    stream.Close();
    int cn = 0;
    if (g_day.Values.Count != 0)
        cn = g_day.Values[g_day.Values.Count - 1].Value;
    Label1.Text = cn.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Use the format feature of the editor so that we can read your code.

Comment: Is this code snippet that you've provided a part of your `Deserialize()` function?

Comment: which version of .NET?  Also, can you post the stack trace?

Comment: It's not a StackOverflowDotComException, is it? :P

Comment: `if (File.Exists(...))` checks are evil.  Don't do it.  Just open the file and handle the exception when the open fails.

Comment: What is the value of fName when the exception occurs?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn May I ask what is wrong with File.Exists for the future?

Comment: Results from File.Exists() are stale by the time you observe them (meaning you still have to handle a FileNotFoundException... the code is wasteful clutter), and it can sometimes return false for files that do exist (leading to data loss if you then decide to create a new file that overwrites the old).

Comment: Basically, you can't assume your code will run fast at all times. In rare cases, the amount of time between `File.Exists` and `File.Open` could be many milliseconds. What if the file is deleted or renamed after the `File.Exists` test and before `File.Open`? Also, what if the file exists and your program does not have permission to access it? In both cases, an `IOException` will occur.  Catch the exception instead of using `File.Exists`.

Answer (score 38):

Your function is probably calling itself recursively an infinite number of times.

Sometimes this happens indirectly: you call a method in the BCL and it calls back to your code, and this keeps repeating. File.Exists is probably not the culprit. Look at your call stack when the error occurs.

Comment: So she just asked and left! Perfect answer!